# Disable logging from SDKs/jars in scala

Tags: scala, logging, logback

I am using logback.xml for logging. I want to disable the logs from 3rd party jars/SDKs. For this I used the log level="OFF" for that jar, but still the logs are getting logged. Next I tried using the same log level for one of my files in codebase, I was able to disable the logs for my file.

Below is my logback config :

'''

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern> Some pattern </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="<sdk file path>" level="OFF"/>         !--- This doesn't work ---!    
<logger name="<file from my codebase>" level="OFF"/>  !--- This works ---!

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

'''

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "file path"? Perhaps give an example with a specific library?

Comment: file path means : org.apache.commons.collections4.bag.AbstractBagDecorator

The complete path of the file in the jar. The above one is just for reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A library can use any `name` it likes for a logger so the `name` will not necessarily match the path of the library.

The `%logger` field in the `pattern` gives the `name` of the logger so you will see the actual name in the logging output. If you see output that you want to suppress, use the `name` from the log (or a prefix) in the `logger` element.

I would also recommend setting the `root` to the lowest level and then increasing the level for the specific libraries that you are interested in.

```
<logger name="myloggername" level="DEBUG"/>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```